# How can i add new fetures to Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I want to add my own feature to Cassandra.

For example, I want cassandra to say `hello world` on start (please don`t tell me that it can be done by modifying  bash-script).

```
class HelloWorldApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
}}
```

Anybody knows, how can I do that?In other words, if i have hand-made script, how can i get Cassandra to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by a "hand-made script"? shell, perl, java application, java class running inside the cassandra VM, ...? Please clarify the use case.

Comment: You mean to say, you have application A and application B and you want to integrate them together such that when application A starts application B should start or A is calling or triggering B, is it?

Comment: when application A starts(in my case it`s Cassandra), it shoud cause start of application B

Answer (score 2):

May Be you are looking for this : [How to Contribute to Cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HowToContribute)

It explains everything from downloading cassandra source code to submitting patches.

To start with(If you are used to Eclipse) you may find this helpful : [Running Cassandra In Eclipse](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInEclipse)

Comment: no, it isn`t thing that i looking for.  I can normally build cassandra from sources and it works. But if i have my own java-class or java-application - how can i add it co cassandra?

Comment: sorry for my English. In other words, i have my own java-application, for example it application says "hello world" when cassandra starts. What i need to do for my code works with cassandra? I downloaded cassandra sources, i wrote an application - and now how can i compile Cassandra with my code? I want Cassandra to say "hello world" when is starts.